# Displaying a select number of blog entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, blogs

I'm fairly new to working with Ruby on Rails.
I've created a blog called "posts", and I want my homepage to display the 2 latest entries...

I've so far got it displaying ALL blog posts using

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
```

but how do I modify this to show only the latest 2?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@posts = Post.order('created_at desc').limit(2)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work I'm afraid

"You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each"

Comment: My mistake, I should've changed "@post" to "@posts". Working fine now! Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo indeed. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're having something like `@posts = Post.all` in your controller, you'd just do the following instead:

```
@posts = Post.last(2)
```

Comment: That certainly worked, however in my controller I actually had
@posts = Post.all(:order => "created_at DESC")
so that blog entries would appear in a time relevant manner.

Is there a way to combine the (:order => "created_at DESC") with your solution? (I did attempt it, but no luck)

Comment: You'd then do something like `@posts = Post.last(2).order('created_at DESC')`.

Comment: No offence, but that will return exactly the opposite. Using last with an explicit order is counter-intuitive, obviously, because you should reverse the wanted order.

Comment: Yup, you're right. Fristly, the order of the method calls is wrong, `last` won't return a Relation. Secondly, using `last` does not work here as intended. Limiting the query is the way to go.